# How do I make modal dialog for a Page in my WPF-application?

Tags: wpf, modal-dialog

I have a WPF Window which has a among other controls hosts a Frame. In that frame I display different pages. Is there way to make a dialog modal to only a page? When I'm showing the dialog it should not be possible to click on any control on the page but it should be possible to click on a control on the same window that is not on the page.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If I am correct in interpreting your message, you want something that works similar to what 
[Billy Hollis demonstrates in his StaffLynx application](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=115).

I recently built a similar control and it turns out that this sort of idea is relatively simple to implement in WPF. I created a custom control called DialogPresenter. In the control template for the custom control, I added markup similar to the following:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local=DialogPresenter}">
  <Grid>
    <ContentControl>
      <ContentPresenter />
    </ContentControl>
    <!-- The Rectangle is what simulates the modality -->
    <Rectangle x:Name="Overlay" Visibility="Collapsed" Opacity="0.4" Fill="LightGrey" />
    <Grid x:Name="Dialog" Visibility="Collapsed">
      <!-- The template for the dialog goes here (borders and such...) -->
      <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_DialogView" />
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <!-- Triggers to change the visibility of the PART_DialogView and Overlay -->
  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I also added a `Show(Control view)` method, which finds the the 'PART_DialogView', and adds the passed in view to the `Content` property.

This then allows me to use the `DialogPresenter` as follows:

```
<controls:DialogPresenter x:Name="DialogPresenter">
  <!-- Normal parent view content here -->
  <TextBlock>Hello World</TextBlock>
  <Button>Click Me!</Button>
</controls:DialogPresenter>
```

To the buttons event handler (or bound command), I simply call the Show() method of the `DialogPresenter`.

You can also easily add ScaleTransform markup to the DialogPresenter template to get scaling effects shown in the video. This solution has neat and tidy custom control code, and a very simple interface for your UI programming team.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, I got the idea from the StaffLynx application. I find it really hard to grok this WPF stuff but I guess it will get easier. To get the dialog to be moveable I guess there are some more things that must be done.

Comment: Certainly - to do the moveable view, you would substitute a Canvas where we have the Grid named "Dialog". You would also have to do all the drag/drop stuff. There is a good overview of this concept at: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/DraggingElementsInCanvas.aspx

Comment: Hi Brad, great answer! Would you share the complete source code of the DialogPresenter? I'd love to use it in one of my projects.
Thanks, Jens.

Comment: I've written up a blog post and released some sample code at: http://bradleach.wordpress.com/2009/02/25/control-level-modal-dialog/

Comment: Its not really modal though. Not like MessageBox.Show() is modal and blocks callers until dismissed. It is pseudo-modal because if used properly it takes over the entire window, but it doesn't block like a modal dialog would.

Comment: You're spot on, @jrwen. The calling code is not blocked when I call Show(). The design I presented was mainly to show how you could do what Billy Hollis showed in his StaffLynx video - which was essentially multiple non-blocking "modal" dialogs. For this style of UI, you would not want to block. That all said, if you want blocking for a single view, it shouldn't be too hard to implement.

Comment: I've used a similar approach to this: blocking click interaction on background controls using a border / rectangle. I realized later that the user can still tab into controls that are behind this "visual shield." May not be a big deal, but it's still there.

Answer (score 4):

I have a project on [github](https://github.com/BenjaminGale/ModalContentPresenter) which is a custom `FrameworkElement` that allows you to display modal content over the primary content.

The control can be used like this:

```
<c:ModalContentPresenter IsModal="{Binding DialogIsVisible}">
    <TabControl Margin="5">
            <Button Margin="55"
                    Padding="10"
                    Command="{Binding ShowModalContentCommand}">
                This is the primary Content
            </Button>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>

    <c:ModalContentPresenter.ModalContent>
        <Button Margin="75"
                Padding="50"
                Command="{Binding HideModalContentCommand}">
            This is the modal content
        </Button>
    </c:ModalContentPresenter.ModalContent>

</c:ModalContentPresenter>
```

Features:

- Displays arbitrary content.
- Does not disable the primary content whilst the modal content is being displayed.
- Disables mouse and keyboard access to the primary content whilst the modal content is displayed.
- Is only modal to the content it is covering, not the entire application.
- can be used in an MVVM friendly way by binding to the `IsModal` property.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use nested message pumps to create modal controls

http://deanchalk.com/wpf-modal-controls-via-dispatcherframe-nested-message-pumps/

Comment: The Link is dead

Answer (score 1):

You are not looking for a modal dialog here. You need a function that will disable the "page" control, show a dialog, and re-enable it when the dialog closes.

I'm not too sure whether you understand what a modal dialog is meant to do though?

Comment: Why the downvote? A Modal window is a window that is the only window that can accept input at that time for an application.