# pop up dialog question

Tags: wpf

I need to create a static text pop up warning message to the user. I'm coming from the Java Swing world, and I know I can do that in one or two lines of code. Is there an equivalent easy method to call to pop up a warning dialog?? I'd rather not get into creating xaml code etc, just for a simple dialog. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: I answered a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726771/show-pop-up-window-when-is-mouser-over-listbox-item/4726871#4726871) yesterday.

Comment: @Slaks: He tagged his question "wpf", that's the wpf's way.

Comment: WPF also has `MessageBox.Show`.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.messagebox.show.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Call [`MessageBox.Show`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.messagebox.show.aspx).