# How do I invoke a modal window from a wpf page?

Tags: wpf, window, modal-dialog

How do I invoke a modal window from a wpf page? Window.showDialog() makes the window modal when it is invoked from a parent Window, however when invoked from a Page, the modal behaviour disappears. I tried using a PopUp control, but it doesnt appear to be as customizable as a window.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173652/how-do-i-make-modal-dialog-for-a-page-in-my-wpf-application

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how are you calling the window, but calling `new Window().ShowDialog()` from within a page inside frame, makes the new window modal to the whole application.