# NotificationWindow in browser silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

is there a way to have NotificationWindow in browser?
I need NotificationWindow in browser not in "out of browser".

Comment: I don't think it is possible. I might be wrong... Just go have a look at the [Dialog Presenter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173652/how-do-i-make-modal-dialog-for-a-page-in-my-wpf-application/173769#173769).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like AnthonyWJones said, in Silverlight 4 the `NotificationWindow` is restricted to Out Of Browser use.

However with Silverlight 5, apps will be able to run in the browser with elevated permission (under certain conditions).

That means that the `NotificationWindow` will work in the browser.

More info on Silverlight 5 in-browser trusted apps [here](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2011/04/27/silverlight-5-beta-rough-notes-trusted-apps-in-the-browser.aspx)

Comment: I'm not sure this information is correct, have you actually tried this?  Its common to confuse "Trusted" features with "OOB".  A non-trusted OOB app can launch NotificationWindows. This restriction is related to how the app is hosted not the security restrictions.  The prelim docs for SL5 still indicate that `NotificationWindow` is limited to OOB (but that part of documentation may still need editing).

Comment: The Silverlight 5 RC documentation on MSDN says "Trusted applications [...] enables you to use the WebBrowser and NotificationWindow classes inside the browser." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721083(v=VS.96).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight exclusively limits `NotificationWindow` to OOB use.  You will need to find something else outside of Silverlight to acheive the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

As guys said, there is no `NotificationWindow` in browser for Silverlight 4. For solving this issue you can choose different ways: first is just to wait for release of SL 5 or on the other hand - implement your own `MessageBox` with desired functionality. Regarding second one I can help with some code samples.

Comment: A messagebox will not deliver the same functionality.

Comment: I am not saying about `MessageBox` as it is in SL4. We should implement own Control that in his functionality will be close to `NotificationWindow`. But still it will not be `NotificationWindow`.

Comment: The very purpose of NotificationWindow is to provide a "Toast" popup that can be visible even when the app is minimized.  There is just no way to reproduce this in-browser or even "be close".  The only part of the user's screen(s) you can affect from in-browser is the plugin's client area.

Comment: Yeah. @AnthonyWJones  you are right. I meant exactly `NotificationWindow` within clients area.