# How to set Dialog Presenter Center screen?

Tags: wpf, templates, xaml, custom-controls, modal-dialog

I am using Brads [Dialog Presenter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173652/how-do-i-make-modal-dialog-for-a-page-in-my-wpf-application/173769#173769).

It works great, but i only have 1 problem...

I can't get it so that the dialog shows Center Screen.

Can anyone help me here please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This 
[converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146719/center-image-inside-canvas)
 worked for me.

In **DialogPresenter.Generic.xaml**

```
<controls:DragCanvas Name="DialogCanvas">
  <Grid x:Name="Dialog"  ...>
    <Canvas.Top>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CenterConverter}" ConverterParameter="top">
            <Binding ElementName="DialogCanvas" Path="ActualWidth" />
            <Binding ElementName="DialogCanvas" Path="ActualHeight" />
            <Binding ElementName="Dialog" Path="ActualWidth" />
            <Binding ElementName="Dialog" Path="ActualHeight" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Canvas.Top>
    <Canvas.Left>
        ...
    </Canvas.Left>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can get the dialog centered.

1. In the DialogPresenter class, update the Show() method to set the window.WindowStartupPosition = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen.
2. Write a custom TriggerAction and override Invoke to do the following.

   var window = Window.GetWindow(this.AssociatedObject);
   window.WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen

   then attach the trigger action to the ControlTemplate in the triggers section.  You would use an EventTrigger using the LoadedEvent and calling your TriggerAction.

Note: If you have ExpressionBlend, it makes dragging TriggerActions to the UI easy because it writes the EventTrigger part for you.