# Center Image inside Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an `Image` inside a `Canvas`:

```
<Canvas>
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Canvas>
```

And I want to display the `Image` *always* (even after a possible resizing) in the center of my `Canvas`, but in this way the image is draw in the Top-Left corner. How can I do?

Comment: I think it can be solved using multibinding with responding converter

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208992/how-to-center-an-element-in-wpf-canvas

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The coolest thing of this aproach taht it would work if you change sizes of both image and canvas.
Converter code:

```
internal sealed class CenterConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double canvasWidth = System.Convert.ToDouble(values[0]);
        double canvasHeight = System.Convert.ToDouble(values[1]);
        double controlWidth = System.Convert.ToDouble(values[2]);
        double controlHeight = System.Convert.ToDouble(values[3]);
        switch ((string)parameter)
        {
            case "top":
                return (canvasHeight - controlHeight) / 2;
            case "bottom":
                return (canvasHeight + controlHeight) / 2;
            case "left":
                return (canvasWidth - controlWidth) / 2;
            case "right":
                return (canvasWidth + controlWidth) / 2;
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

XAML, somewhere in resources:

```
    <local:CenterConverter x:Key="CenterConverter" />
```

XAML:

```
<Canvas x:Name="superCoolCanvas">
    <Image x:Name="superCoolImage" >
        <Canvas.Top>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CenterConverter}" ConverterParameter="top">
                <Binding ElementName="superCoolCanvas" Path="ActualWidth" />
                <Binding ElementName="superCoolCanvas" Path="ActualHeight" />
                <Binding ElementName="superCoolImage" Path="ActualWidth" />
                <Binding ElementName="superCoolImage" Path="ActualHeight" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </Canvas.Top>
        <Canvas.Left>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CenterConverter}" ConverterParameter="left">
                <Binding ElementName="superCoolCanvas" Path="ActualWidth" />
                <Binding ElementName="superCoolCanvas" Path="ActualHeight" />
                <Binding ElementName="superCoolImage" Path="ActualWidth" />
                <Binding ElementName="superCoolImage" Path="ActualHeight" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </Canvas.Left>
    </Image>
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

Canvas is intended to use absolute coordinates. You may use solution provided by dwrd or put Canvas and Image both in Grid and then center the Image in this Grid.

Comment: Since the image is a child of the canvas do you mean center the canvas in the grid?

Comment: Yes, this is the daily basis solution.