# WPF GUI-Animations

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to WPF and therefore this might be a stupid question, but I try to create a GUI with some nice animations and I dont know if this is possible with WPF and if it is possible, I dont know where to start.

What I am looking for is an animated search-textbox which expands when it is focused ( just like this [example](http://thefinishedbox.com/files/freebies/jquerysearch/index.html) ).
Another thing I would like to add to my GUI is a modal panel which animates like this: [example](http://okonet.ru/projects/modalbox/index.html).
And is it possible to exchange two panels iPhone-like ( -> slidedeck.com ).

Thank you very much!

Comment: Animation Overview on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx

Comment: This is definitely possible. This is what WPF is best at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Task you described is 100% solvable with WPF. Take a look at these articles:

**Expand textbox on hover**

- [Expanding Textbox on hover](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/920ca781-db8a-423e-98c4-82c95eb4c11e)

**Modal panels**

- [How do I make modal dialog for a Page in my WPF-application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173652/how-do-i-make-modal-dialog-for-a-page-in-my-wpf-application/173769#173769)

**General articles about animation in WPF**

- [WPF Tutorial - Styles, Triggers & Animation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140623/WPF-Tutorial-Styles-Triggers-Animation)
- [Beginner's WPF Animation Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23257/Beginner-s-WPF-Animation-Tutorial)
- [Animation Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx)
- [Basic Animation in WPF Using XAML](http://windowsclient.net/learn/video.aspx?v=11992)