# WPF: Adorner + Popup = Modal Popup

Tags: wpf, popupwindow

So here's the idea of it...

I have an application that I am designing with WPF. It has a Main Window with a frame inside to navigate through pages. The navigation aspect is done through the window (kind of like a template with a footer that has the navigation controls) and the pages have the individual content. On certain pages I would like to have an **ADD (+)** button that causes a popup that has a form inside to add personal information to the database (First name, last name, address, .etc) While this popup is open I would not like them to be able to access any other part of the application until they press OK or CANCEL. I'd like to be able to call this popup from the individual pages unless there is another workaround.

Any ideas or assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: I've never liked WPF popups, and use a CustomUserControl that is laid overtop of the rest of my panel/screen/application instead. If you're interested, the code for it can be found [here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/popup-panel-for-wpf/). It's pretty basic, and easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

some wpf popups [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173652/how-do-i-make-modal-dialog-for-a-page-in-my-wpf-application/173769#173769) and [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36516/WPF-Modal-Dialog).